# How to use pywinauto to set_text in python IDLE editor?

Tags: python, python-idle

I want to control python IDLE with pywinauto.

I can start IDLE but cannot input text.

Here is my code:

```
import pywinauto
app = pywinauto.application.Application(backend="uia").start(r"C:\Python37\pythonw.exe C:\Python37\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw")
app2 = pywinauto.application.Application().connect(process=app.process)
```

I tried to use `app2.Property.print_control_identifiers()` but it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 256, in __resolve_control
    criteria)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 458, in wait_until_passes
    raise err

pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    app2.Property.print_control_identifiers()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 595, in print_control_identifiers
    this_ctrl = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)[-1]
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 259, in __resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 436, in wait_until_passes
    func_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 201, in __get_ctrl
    dialog = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**criteria[0]))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 84, in find_element
    elements = find_elements(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 303, in find_elements
    elements = findbestmatch.find_best_control_matches(best_match, wrapped_elems)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findbestmatch.py", line 533, in find_best_control_matches
    raise MatchError(items = name_control_map.keys(), tofind = search_text)
pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'Property' in 'dict_keys(['*Python 3.7.2 Shell*TkTopLevel', '*Python 3.7.2 Shell*', 'TkTopLevel'])'
```

How to solve the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app = pywinauto.application.Application(backend="uia").start(r"C:\Python37\pythonw.exe C:\Python37\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw")
app2 = pywinauto.application.Application().connect(process=app.process)
app3 = app2.top_window()
app3.print_control_identifiers()
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you can do whatever it is that you are trying to do.  The [pywinauto site](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) says "pywinauto is a set of python modules to automate the Microsoft Windows GUI. At its simplest it allows you to send mouse and keyboard actions to windows dialogs and controls."  IDLE uses tkinter, which uses the tcl/tk gui framework.  While that ultimately uses Windows graphics, it may not be at the level that pywinauto accesses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyautogui which is best for windows GUI automation

I converted RDP connection to automation using pyautogui

```
import pyautogui
import time
import os

os.system("C:\\Users\Administrator\\Desktop\\RDC.bat")
print(pyautogui.position())
time.sleep(5)

pyautogui.click(490,404)
pyautogui.typewrite("Bitwise$123")
pyautogui.typewrite(["Enter"])
```